# Formula for crank/piston setup

Tags: classical-mechanics

I’m not totally certain how to ask this question or what mechanism this is, but I’m trying to know how far the bottom of a vertical object will travel when pushed straight down from the top.

```
Excertion
   |
   |
   |
   |<——- What is diaganol travel?


Exertion
   \
    \
     \
How ->\
Far 
Did this move?
```

If the bar moves down 10 inches, did it also move across the ground 10 inches at the bottom? Or what is the formula for this?

Comment: You're interested in horizontal displacement, right?

Comment: I have a hint for you: Pythagoras. You can also use trigonometry.

Comment: Maybe useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piston_motion_equations